# Can we pipe two RxJS timout methods with same request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, rxjs, request-timed-out

I am trying to identify if my resource is failing due to timeouts and at the same time want to analyze how many failures are with timeouts. So, I am trying to attach one timeout with request which will simply log saying request not recieved within time, without throwing error and another timeout will throw the error. Something like this:

```
const checkResponseTimeouts = async () => {
  const data = await firstValueFrom(
    from(getData())
      .pipe(
        timeout({
          each: 2500,
          with: ( sub ) => { // this is not the way it works, but just to make example
            console.log("response not recieved within 2.5 seconds");
            return true;
          },
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        timeout({
          each: 10000,
          with: () => {
            console.log("request timed out after 10 seconds");
            return throwError(() => new Error("Some error"));
          },
        })
      )
  );

  return data;
};
```

The code above is not correct, its just for demonstrating the problem. I am new to RxJS and few things seems confusing to me. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to sent request with `getData()` and get notified after 2.5 seconds and 10 seconds if `getData()` haven't returned value yet, but not cancel the request. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, just that not to cancel in 2.5s but cancel after 10s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom operator for this, that would be generic and therefore reusable.

```js
const sideEffectAfterXMs =
  (ms: number, sideEffect: () => void) =>
  <T>(obs$: Observable<T>) =>
    race(
      obs$,
      new Observable((observer) => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(sideEffect, ms);
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
      })
    );
```

We create a `race` between the original observable and one that we create ourselves. The one we create ourselves never emits, which ensures that the `race` can only be won by the original observable. But within our observable, we call a callback after a certain amount of time. Most importantly, we cleanup the `timeout` if the observable is closed, which could only happen if the original observable emits first or throw.

Then to use it:

```js
of('Hello world!')
  .pipe(
    delay(11_000),
    sideEffectAfterXMs(2500, () => console.log('Side effect!')),
    timeout(5_000)
  )
  .subscribe(
    (x) => console.log(`Value received: ${x}`),
    (e) => console.log(`Error: ${e}`),
    () => console.log(`Complete`)
  );
```

If we apply a short delay, we get this output:

```
Value received: Hello world!
Complete
```

If we apply a delay that is above the `2500` ms timeout for the side effect but below the `5000` timeout to throw, we get this output:

```
Side effect!
Value received: Hello world!
Complete
```

And if we apply a delay that is greater than the `5000` ms timeout, we get this output:

```
Side effect!
Error: TimeoutError: Timeout has occurred
```

Here's a [live demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-snt7xp?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts) that you can play with.

Comment: Thanks maxime1992, I will check if this works for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @maxime1992! This worked very well for me! And thanks for detailed explanation.